# Inserting text into bash terminal as user from script

Tags: bash

I cannot figure out how to insert a string into a bash terminal.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

```
$./insert.sh
$this was inserted by script[Cursor is here]
```

I would still like to be able to edit "this was inserted by script". It **should not be executed** without pressing enter.Like pasting into a terminal will leave the text without executing it (Assuming no newlines).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Gruber, ...without getting into nonportable hackery, using something other than an external script (ie. readline configuration or extensions), or running your shell under `expect`, the exact thing you're asking for isn't possible. You can do things that are similar -- creating an editable command that will be run *by your script*, not by the parent shell, for instance. Knowing more about your use case would let us suggest something that suffices for your actual purpose and is feasible to implement in a robust and portable manner.

Comment: Also, on SuperUser, see [populate command line from script](http://superuser.com/questions/1023185/populate-command-line-from-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read` builtin:

```
read -e -p'$ ' -i 'this was inserted by script' var_name
```

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants that text to be queued up *as the next command to run* (by the parent shell invoking the script, as opposed to by the script itself). I don't see how this accomplishes that.

Comment: Yeah, it seems pretty clear to me that he's trying to emulate user input for the shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Probably I was misreading the question. *this was inserted by the script* didn't sound like a command to me.